# split fastq file containing a sequence block at different locations

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, clustering

I have some fastq files (obtained from nanopore sequencing) that contain reads that can be of either of these 5 forms:

- a known CDS with 3'UTR:

```
CDS----------------------- (seq1: original sequence)
```

- the same cds with a block of 50bp represented by `|||||` (that substitutes the 3'UTR at 4 different locations)

```
CDS|||||------------------ (sub1: substitution 1)
CDS-----|||||------------- (sub2: substitution 2)
CDS----------|||||-------- (sub3: substitution 3)
CDS---------------|||||--- (sub4: substitution 4)
```

I need to split my fastq files in 5 smaller files clustering the different types of sequences (seq1, sub1, sub2, sub3 and sub4). The problem is that those sequences all share some segments and I don't know which method I should apply. I tried finding the best match by building a BLAST database with the 5 sequences but as it is local alignments, I get HSPs for each sequences and cannot discriminate between them.

Does anyone has an idea how I could achieve that?

Any help would be amazing.

**edit**

Here are 5 sequences as I expect them (i.e., fasta reference)

```
>seq1 (this one does not have the 50bp block)
ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCTACAACTTTTGAGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTATTGTCTCTTTTGGTTTATTTTTCTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATAAA
>sub1
_GTAAGTGAGGGAGTCTCGGACTCAATTAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCACA_ TTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCTACAACTTTTGAGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTATTGTCTCTTTTGGTTTATTTTTCTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATAAA
>sub2
ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACT _GTAAGTGAGGGAGTCTCGGACTCAATTAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCACA_ TTTGAGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTATTGTCTCTTTTGGTTTATTTTTCTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATAAA
>sub3
ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCTACAACT _GTAAGTGAGGGAGTCTCGGACTCAATTAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCACA_ TTGTCTCTTTTGGTTTATTTTTCTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATAAA
>sub4
ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCTACAACTTTTGAGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTA _GTAAGTGAGGGAGTCTCGGACTCAATTAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCACA_ GATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATAAA
```

**examples (50bp block if present is in lowercase here)**

- this read should be associated with sub3 because of the flanking sequences (...CTACAACT in 5' and TTGTCTCTTTT... in 3' of the 50 bp block)

```
@e213fdd5-bbfb-4dfe-9b03-29eea256da0d 
TGTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTACTAGTTATTGAGTGTCTTTGTGTTTCTGTTGGTGCGTCTTCGCACAAGGCTAATCTTACTCTCCTCTCCAATGTACTGCTTCTATGTTCATCTCAGCCGAATTCAATAAGGAGAAGAACTTTCACTAGGTTTCCCCATTCTGTTCGATTAATTGGTGATGTTAGTAAATTTCAATTTTCTGTCGGTGGAAGGTGAAGGTGATTGCTGCTGGCTTTTCATTGTTTACTTTTGGCTTCTGTTTTGTAGTAACGCATCACTACTTTCTCTTATAGTGTTCAATGCTTTCCAAGTCTGGAATCATGAAGCAGCGGCTTCTTCAAGAGCGCCATGCCTGAGGGATACGTGCAGGAGAGGACCATCTTCTTCAAGGACGACGGGAACTACAAGACGTGCTGAAGTCAAGTTTGGGGAGACACCCTCGTCAATGAGATCGAGCTTAAGGGAATCGATTTCAAGGAGGACGGAAACATCCTCGGCCACAAGTTGGAATACAACTACAACTCCCACAACGTATACATCATAGCCGACAAAACCCAAAAGACGGCATCAAGAAACCAACTTCAGACCTTACCATCAGGCGGCGGCCATCACACAGTCATTGTCAACAAATGTAATTGGCGGTGGCTATTCTTTTTACCCAGACAACCATTACCTTGTCCACACAGTCACACTGTGAAAAGATCCCAACTTTGAAAGAGAGGCCACTGGTCTTCTTGAGTTTGTAACAACTGCTGGGATTACACATGGCATGGATGAACTATACAAACATGACAGACTCTAAAGCCTGCAGTTCCTGAAGAGATTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCTACAACTgtaagtgagggagtctcggactcaattagaggctcttctttcacaTTGTCTCTTTTGGTTTATTTTCTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTTTCCTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATGCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACTGTAGGCACCATCAATGAAGATAGAGCGACAGGCAAGTCACAAAAACACCGACAACTTTCTTGTCACGGTAGGCGATAGCAATACGTAACTG
+
$&&&%234441124--585545;>B99968650-++*()'&'(;D540488?=888,++*+*)*$$$##&%$$$%)*****('%$$'1/+++-,('))'%$$%$$$&)&%%%&(*'&),/'''&&'06872..*&%)),,3/49:;<?A773)('()/066+'&&)('(+&%$&''$$&&()*--888)('()'')')'''++*+)&')&$$$%()'')*''&&))&'&$&(&$#$%&%&&&%%$%&..&%%%%&&%$%&'&$$'-)(%%%$&(*,+****&'''('+17<{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{<?BB-,,-13444/154///933{3==@B:9989::::::;;<<=:3335=EBB;:*)..'-:69?@CKKKDC<<?>:)()((012.,,+,55;=?>@>:98:78544344*)%$$$&)))))))))(((((''''&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&')+.1866677978:;;:::;;;99::988889653456:::9889;::8899.,+0668:;:::8436735//:632/-,+**+013459;9332/+($
```

- this read should be associated with sub4 because of the flanking sequences (...TTTTACTCCTA in 5' even if a C is missing, and GATCTTGTCCT... in 3')

```
@107dfd6d-2101-4fd8-aeb5-2c432e176d72 
ATGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTATCGCCTACCGTGACAAGAAAGTTGTCGGTGTCTTTGTGTTTCTGTTGGTGCTGATATTGCATGAAGACTAATCTTTTCTCTTTCTCATCTTTTCACTTCTCCTATCATTATCCTCGACCGAATTCAGTAAAGGAGAAGAACTTTTCACTGGGTTGTCCCAATTCTTGTTGAATTAGATGGTGATGTTAATGGGTACAAATTTTCTGTCAGTGGAAGAGGGTGAAGGTGATGCAACATACGGAAAACTTACCCTTAAATTTATTTGCACTACTGGAAAACTACCTGTTCCATGGCCAACACTTGTCACTACTTTCTCTTATGGTGTTCAATGCTTTCAAGATACCAGATCATATGAAGCGGCACGACTTCTTCAAGAGCGCCATGCCTGAGGGATACGTGCGGGAGAGGACCATCTTCTTCAAGGACGACGGGAACTACAAGACACGTGCTGAAGTCAAGTTTGAGGAGACACCCTCGTCAACAGGATCGAGCTTAAGGGAATCGATTTCAAGGAGGACGGAAACATCCTCGGCCACAAGTTGGAATACAACCGCAACTCCCACAACGTATACATCATGGCCGACAAGCAAAAGAACGGCATCAAAGCCAACTTCAAGACCCGCCACAACATCGAAGACGGCGGCGTGCAACTCGCTGATCATTATCAACAAAATACTCCAATTGGCGATGGCCTGTCCTTTTACCAGACAACCATTACCTGTCCACACAATCTGCCCTTTCGAAAGATCCCAACGAAAAATTTTTGCATGGTCCTTCTTGAGTTTGTAACGGCTGCTGGGATTACATGGCATGGATGAAGAACTGCAACACAAACACTTGACGAACTCTAAACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGAAATTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCACCAACTTTTGAGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCTAgtaagtgagggagtctcggactcaattagaggctcttctttcacaGATCTTGTCCTCTTTTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTCATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACTGTAGGCACCATCAATGAAGATAGAGCGACAGGCAAGTCACAAAGACACCGACAACTTTCTTGTCACGGTAGGCGATAGCAATACGTAACT
+
-0,+))),:::<??===>=<<<?@>=<<=?;:889:<;<<=;;;;CD@?:9:A>9999=999DBAA@<BE=3220111<B@@AA@A?>>>=>>;:9999:9;<E9A<;?????C8788;==@?;;;==9989@A6677?=7788+**+368>B87::==@<99;<<<<<<??>@=:9/.))*698.*,/8A=<==>>=?BAB=::::;;;<?@>@B@@?:888:>?@CCCEDB>??>===::.+)()2157=7:99<B?>???@??=;::=DGC=<6?;84568>AB@CCBCBAA====AAACEI{AA=<::;<?@=<<>=>@AAA@>>>>?<?====A?==<=@>??@>?==??CA@AAA@AB=757:965(*.;<;<::?AAA@>=>::::<=?@BCC5336899=?>>?@A??42220;9:89.-***+77;97<;:;<<??BC{878<:9:<:2112<<>===@=<;;<>???877/,.-.-///0,++,)299:=;:;;=@@<;=7778?=::;;<;=<<C>AB<BBBCEDCDC?A>;;9:655:DAA@?>>>=?=><;<<@=>><=B=@=:870++,,;=;>><<==CBA@?>=>>=667<;;7778B>B?B<<==<99:::4:659;6642212:.-<=??=6556;??@@>::;:==;8887899==;2143235<<<?>==?CEBD?>>>ADB=720/.02334<00//06568>:888:711*)-776'''&06:<=><><866;{C@A?>8897=>EK558568552-179664)(()),,--,()))3:;:<BAAA>=>>>><<>>*))+/245999;>>=96;?B9888<<77-,,,,&&%%%&&'+6;A;2111--,,.:;><<ACCA@@?=9;;;>=>==@930../+)(())07>>8<><;:;9238<>=>998878:7700016545**1236434689<9<<;.--0-,,,&'():78862237@???><;;;;<<=@>@??@@===;<=>>;:8;)(67511223/.---.2001023:;21<?=**6223;;>?AACGA=73366:;<=:766;ACC=<;86000?8=@DHEC@@=;;<9999<<==9><==8889>A>=;30266777:972+***)))'&%%%%%$$$$$$######"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""#&')+-1122/...46688<<=0('%%&258899;92136:999;:::9:;;--2-.343668=<?@EF????==:7668;6667;><<;;>;;8851.*
```

Comment: @terdon, I added two examples. I cannot provide all cases, as I actually have 16 of them and i'm having a hard time doing it by hand. I still hope that it is clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [seqkit locate](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#locate) with say start or end of CDS sequence. This will give you a tabulated output with locations of your CDS query in each read.
Since you expect that the CDS sequence should be located at one of the five different locations inside your reads you can figure out to which one of the five a given read belongs.

You may also use [clumpify.sh from BBMap](https://github.com/BioInfoTools/BBMap/blob/master/sh/clumpify.sh) to cluster reads prior to searching for the CDS locations. The idea is that maybe the five groups will cluster in fairly well separated blocks, but this is fairly speculative.

*edit*

Since the alignment of your sequences looks like this:

```
CLUSTAL 2.1 multiple sequence alignment


sub1            NNNNNNNNNNGTAAGTGAGGGAGTCTCGGACTCAAT---TAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCACANN
sub2            --ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTNNNNNNNNNNGTA
seq1            --ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGG-
sub3            --ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGGC
sub4            --ACCTGCCAGTTCCTGAAGGGTGTACTGATCCTGTGGCTGAAAACTTTGATCCAACGG-
                          **   *** **     * **  *  *   *  *  **             

sub1            NNNNNNNNTTGATCCAACGGCTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTG---TGTCTACAACTTTTG
sub2            AGTGAGGGAGTCTCGGACT-CAATTAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCAC---ANNNNNNNNNNTTTG
seq1            --------------------CTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTG---TGTCTACAACTTTTG
sub3            TAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTGTGTCTACAACTNNNNNNNNNNGTAAGTGAGGGAGTCTCG
sub4            --------------------CTAGAAGTGACGATGGAACCTG---TGTCTACAACTTTTG
                                              *                          * *

sub1            AGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTATTGTCTCTTT-----TGGT
sub2            AGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTATTGTCTCTTT-----TGGT
seq1            AGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTATTGTCTCTTT-----TGGT
sub3            GACTCAATTAGA--GGCTCTTCTTTCACANNNNNNNNNN--TTGTCTCTTT-----TGGT
sub4            AGCAATATTATCCTGCTTATTAATTTGCTGTTTTACTCCTANNNNNNNNNNGTAAGTGAG
                  *   ****    *  * **  **  *                            **  

sub1            TTATTTTT---------------CTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTT
sub2            TTATTTTT---------------CTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTT
seq1            TTATTTTT---------------CTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTT
sub3            TTATTTTT---------------CTCCTTTGTGTAATTGTGGATTGGATCTTGTCCTCTT
sub4            GGAGTCTCGGACTCAATTAGAGGCTCTTCTTTCACANNNNNNNNNNGATCTTGTCCTCTT
                  * * *                *** * * *   *          **************

sub1            TTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTC
sub2            TTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTC
seq1            TTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTC
sub3            TTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTC
sub4            TTGTTCCCTTTTTTTTTTTTTATGATGTACAACACATTGGTAATTTAAAATTGCCTTGTC
                ************************************************************

sub1            ATAAA
sub2            ATAAA
seq1            ATAAA
sub3            ATAAA
sub4            ATAAA
                *****
```

instead of CDS end/start you have to select regions around your deletions with say 15-20bp flanks on each side. Put these in fasta and run locate.

**caveat**
running with zero mismatches will miss some reads.

**edit 2**

The command:

```
zcat input.fq.gz | seqkit locate --threads 8 \
--max-mismatch 0 \
--pattern-file fasta_with_5_frags_extracted_from_algnt.fa > result.tsv
```

Some trial and error is required to select good fragments matching exactly one of the five groups plus increasing `max-mismatch` if due to sequencing errors a lot of reads were dropped.
To speed up IO one can compress `result.tsv` on the fly, i.e. using `pigz` or `zstd`.

In the next step we need to create five separate files listing read names containing a given fragment:

```
grep frag_name_1 result.tsv | cut -f 1 > frag_name_1.read_names.txt

seqkit grep --pattern-file frag_name_1.read_names.txt input.fq.gz -o frag_name_1.reads.fq.gz

# repeat five times with different pattern file and changing the output
```

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I actually think that this method can work.
I have tried to use seqkit locate to find the 50bp block and ran it a second time to locate the end of the CDS. Then, if I compute the distance between the two, I get distances roughly multiple of 50, which allows me to distinguish the sequences group I am after. I am going to try and make something quite clean and then I will post here my solution!